# How to use the <i> tag with ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I am trying to use the "i" tag with the ternary operator. The two strings "unavailable","available" are working perfectly, but instead of those, I want to use 2 icons like a check sign(fa fa-check) and an X sign(fa fa-times).

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<td th:text="${phone.assigned == true ? 'unavailable' : 'available'}" >Availability</td>

<td class="checkSign"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
<td class="xSign"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
```

Comment: Which framework are you using ?

Comment: Yes. I am using thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IF?

```
<td>
  <i th:if="${phone.assigned == true}" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i th:if="${phone.assigned == false}" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `th:classappend`

```
<td class="checkSign"><i class="fa" th:classappend="${phone.assigned} ? fa-check : fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="checkSign"><i class="${phone.assigned === true ? fa fa-check : fa fa-times}" aria-hidden="true"></i>Availability</td>
```

Comment: I believe you are missing quotes around the actual class-names.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to do this is what `th:classappend` (the other answer is missing quotes around the values which would cause an error).  This works:

```
<td>
  <i class="fa" th:classappend="${phone.assigned ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</td>
```

That being said, the other solution does work, but it's a bit silly to compare `booleans` to `true` and `false`.  If you go with that solution, it should look like this:

```
<td>
  <i th:if="${phone.assigned}" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i th:if="${!phone.assigned}" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
</td>
```

or this:

```
<td>
  <i th:if="${phone.assigned}" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i th:unless="${phone.assigned}" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is almost 2 years old but if someone needs it.
I use it this way.

```
<td>
 <i th:class="${phone.assigned}?'fa fa-check':'fa fa times'" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</td>
```